# UICollectionView reuse cells too frequent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I know how to reuse cells and I know how to not reuse cells, but that's not what I'm asking.

What I need is still reusing some cells but make it less frequent.

Let's say I've 10 cells presenting on the screen(each cell with animating GIF file in it, so setting up a cell is consuming), what the `UICollectionView` doing now is like allocate 10 blocks of memory for each of the cells that is being presented, and make reuse of the memory when new cells are coming. This has made the reuse too frequent, so it is setting up the cells all the time and has made the scrolling of the `UICollectionView` a bit slow.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ItemView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ITEM_VIEW_REUSE_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ItemData *itemData = [[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setItemData:itemData];

    return cell;
}
```

I'm thinking, is there a way that I can modify the internal reuse system. Like allocate 30 blocks of memory for each of the cells that is being presented and some cells that are not even presented, so it is not setting up the cells all the time, and I believe that will accelerate the performance of my app.

Comment: perhaps you might want to override `- (void)prepareForReuse` in a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and prepare your cells there. Might be that this is not what you're asking for, but it's just an idea

Comment: if the GIFs are taking time to set up, maybe you can preload them somehow so they aren't recreated/setup every time a new cell pops up.